# inputs are not being stored in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, django

i am currently having an issue with my program my some of my input are not being saved in the MySQL database - any help will be appreciated

this creates a custom user which are the employee, admin and senior employee - this is a different model so another table

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data=((1,"Admin"),(2,"senioremployee"),(3,"employee"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type_data,max_length=20)
```

this the model for one of my usertypes

```
class senioremployee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Dob = models.DateField()
    Nationality = models.TextField()
    Address = models.TextField()
    Postcode = models.TextField()
    Telephone = models.TextField()
    Wage = models.TextField()
    Passportnumber = models.TextField()
    passportexpirydate = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_pic = models.FileField()
    kinname = models.TextField()
    kinrelation = models.TextField()
    kinaddress = models.TextField()
    kinphonenumber = models.TextField()
    kinemail = models.TextField()
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

this function add user's data to the table

```
@receiver(post_save,sender = CustomUser)
def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type==1:
            admin.objects.create(admin = instance,Dob="",Nationality="",Address="",Postcode="",Telephone="",Wage="",Passportnumber="",passportexpirydate="",gender="",profile_pic="",kinname="",kinrelation="",kinaddress="",kinphonenumber="",kinemail = "")
        if instance.user_type==2:
            senioremployee.objects.create(admin = instance,Dob="",Nationality="",Address="",Postcode="",Telephone="",Wage="",Passportnumber="",passportexpirydate="",gender="",profile_pic="",kinname="",kinrelation="",kinaddress="",kinphonenumber="",kinemail = "")
        if instance.user_type==3:
            employee.objects.create(admin = instance,Dob="",Nationality="",Address="",Postcode="",Telephone="",Wage="",Passportnumber="",passportexpirydate="",gender="",profile_pic="",kinname="",kinrelation="",kinaddress="",kinphonenumber="",kinemail = "")
```

this is the function that is meant to save the inputs into the senioremployee's table and email,password , firstname, lastname,username into the custom user's table but currently it only stores email,password , firstname, lastname,username into the custom user's table and just ignores the other user inputs

```
def add_seniorEmployee_save(request):
    if request.method!="POST":
        return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
    else:
        first_name=request.POST.get("first_name")
        last_name=request.POST.get("last_name")
        username=request.POST.get("username")
        email=request.POST.get("email")
        password=request.POST.get("password")
        Dob=request.POST.get("Dob")
        Nationality=request.POST.get("Nationality")
        Address=request.POST.get("Address")
        Postcode=request.POST.get("Postcode")
        Telephone=request.POST.get("Telephone")
        Wage=request.POST.get("Wage")
        Passportnumber=request.POST.get("Passportnumber")
        passportexpirydate=request.POST.get("passportexpirydate")
        gender=request.POST.get("gender")
        kinname=request.POST.get("kinname")
        kinrelation=request.POST.get("kinrelation")
        kinaddress=request.POST.get("kinaddress")
        kinphonenumber=request.POST.get("kinphonenumber")
        kinemail=request.POST.get("kinemail")
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,user_type=2)
            
            user.senioremployee.Dob = Dob
            user.senioremployee.Nationality = Nationality
            user.senioremployee.Address = Address
            user.senioremployee.Postcode = Postcode
            user.senioremployee.Telephone = Telephone
            user.senioremployee.Wage = Wage
            user.senioremployee.Passportnumber = Passportnumber
            
            user.senioremployee.passportexpirydate = passportexpirydate
            user.senioremployee.gender = gender
            user.senioremployee.profile_pic=""
            user.senioremployee.kinname = kinname
            user.senioremployee.kinrelation = kinrelation
            user.senioremployee.kinaddress = kinaddress
            user.senioremployee.kinphonenumber = kinphonenumber
            user.senioremployee.kinemail = kinemail
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Added Senior Employee")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/add_seniorEmployee")
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Couldnt add senior employee")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/add_seniorEmployee")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have a problem with your `senioremployee` creation query. You are using `Dob` and `passportexpirydate` as `DateField`.

```
class senioremployee(models.Model):
    Dob = models.DateField()
    passportexpirydate = models.DateField()
```

But when you are creating `senioremployee` record you are passing empty string which eventually produce exception.

**post_save signal**

```
    try:
        senioremployee.objects.create(admin = instance,Dob="",Nationality="",Address="",Postcode="",Telephone="",Wage="",Passportnumber="",passportexpirydate="",gender="",profile_pic="",kinname="",kinrelation="",kinaddress="",kinphonenumber="",kinemail = "")
    except Exception as e:
        print("e)
```

It will return the exception

```
 ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

so pass YYYY-MM-DD date format to `Dob` and `passportexpirydate` then `senioremployee` will be created.

When you are updating record, you are saving `user` model again which again raise `post_save` signal and you will be creating duplicate `senioremployee` record which return  `UNIQUE constraint failed`.

So you must use this line of code to update `senioremployee` record

```
user.senioremployee.save()
```

instead of

```
user.save()
```